# What are considered Express based frameworks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am looking at taking a simple job to build a web app and one of the requirements is to "use node.js with an express based framework."

I am assuming this means use node.js with express.js but what does an express based framework mean? Are they referring to the templating engine? Would angular.js be consider express based?

I googled "express based frameworks" but did not find a clear answer.

Comment: It's probably something that builds on top of express.js

Comment: Examples: [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/), [Feathers](http://feathersjs.com/), etc.

Comment: So no Angular? Would EJS be considered express based?

Comment: @osiris355 Perhaps you can ask the person who specified that to clarify? It's always best to get it directly from the client. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you saw that or read that, but to answer your questions. Many company take open source libraries and build on top of them. For example Kraken.js, it's a framework built on top of express (by paypal I believe).

Don't google express based. Look for frameworks that extend express.js. You won't find too many. Connect.js is much more commonly extended (express extended for a while, in fact all the naming convention was adopted from connect.js

Answer (score 0):

You can create a web app without Express, but Express will give you a easy  way to create in a short time. Express has a lot of excellent APIs, You can check from docs([Express API Doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)). With express-generator( npm install -g express-generator), you can get a simple express web app in one second.

Express will also support different template engine, like ejs or handlebar.

Angular is just a client-side JavaScript framework, you can create a front-end app communicate with node back-end server using restful API. That's not very hard.Just be careful the secure problem from API communication.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question the OP was asking.  They're not asking what ExpressJS is, but what is meant by the somewhat broader phrase "Express-based frameworks".